# PHP, ajax, HTML form to upload file to google cloud storage

Tags: php, ajax, google-app-engine, cloud-storage

I've seen a bunch of questions asking the same thing, but I can not figure out what the issue here is. I'm trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage through PHP, ajax and HTML:

PHP File

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $errors= array();
    // Authentication with Google Cloud Platform
    $client = new StorageClient(['keyFilePath' => 'qpack-325-13-9bc27ee4320d.json']);
    $bucket = $client->bucket('qpack-13-img');

    // Upload a file to the bucket.
    $bucket->upload(
    fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r')
    );
}

?>
```

JQuery/Ajax:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on('submit', '#imageUpload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($('#imageUpload').get(0));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'config.php',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function ($data) {
            console.log('Succcess');
            $('#success').attr('hidden', false);
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

And HTML:

```
<form id="imageUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <button type="submit">Use this photo</button>
</form>
```

But it will not work! It doesn't throw any errors, the ajax call logs 'Success' but nothing is being uploaded to the bucket. I gave allUsers Storage Object Viewer permissions and I'm testing it on a deploy and still nothing. Am I missing something, because I can't seem to figure it out.

I thought maybe it had something to do with the app.yaml so I'm including it here:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: .

# [START gae_flex_storage_yaml]
env_variables:
  GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET: "***"
# [END gae_flex_storage_yaml]
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you have given the `Storage Object Viewer` permissions, but these are not enough to create files on your storage, if you check the [Object Permissions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions), you can check that you should be using `storage.objects.create` to create files, also it might be interesting to consider giving `storage.objects.update` and `storage.objects.delete` permissions depending on app's needs.

**NOTE**: There is probably an error happening on the background and being catched or treated somehow, but a success state is being throwed to your AJAX call anyway.

Comment: I've tried that and still nothing. I edited the question to include the yaml file, since maybe that's the issue. I've tried making the key an environment variable on my computer (windows) but that didn't work. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Are there any files already in the bucket? Try adding one manually to check if everything is working properly and try to run your app again.